# Lifetime for Iterator field

Tags: iterator, rust

In learning this new fascinating language I wrote this code which outputs 0 through 10 multiplied by 3:

```
pub struct Multiplier {
    factor : int,
    current : int
}
impl Multiplier {
    pub fn new(factor : int) -> Multiplier {
        Multiplier {
            factor: factor,
            current: 0
        }
    }
}
impl Iterator<int> for Multiplier {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<int> {
        if self.current > 10 {
            None
        }
        else {
            let current = self.current;
            self.current += 1;
            Some(current * self.factor)
        }
    }
}

struct Holder {
    x : Multiplier
}
impl Holder {
    pub fn new(factor : int) -> Holder {
        Holder {
            x : Multiplier::new(factor)
        }
    }

    fn get_iterator(&self) -> Multiplier {
        self.x
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut three_multiplier = Holder::new(3).get_iterator();
    for item in three_multiplier {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

If I change `Holder` from this

```
struct Holder {
    x : Multiplier
}
```

to this:

```
struct Holder {
    x : Iterator<int>
}
```

I get a compilation warning:

```
<anon>:27:9: 27:22 error: explicit lifetime bound required
<anon>:27     x : Iterator<int>
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can anyone explain why changing the field type requires an explicit lifetime? I know how to mark the lifetimes but I'm not sure why the compiler wants me to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a lifetime bound this way:

```
struct Holder<'a> {
    x: Iterator<int>+'a
}
```

Note however that this way, the `Holder` struct is *unsized*, because it contains a trait object, which is unsized. This severely limits what you can do with the type: for example, you can not return a `Holder` directly.

You can fix this by making `Holder` accept a type parameter:

```
struct Holder<T> where T: Iterator<int> {
    x : T
}
```

Let's change `get_iterator` to use the type parameter:

```
impl<T> Holder<T> where T: Iterator<int>+Copy {
    fn get_iterator(&self) -> T {
        self.x
    }
}
```

*Note:* I added the `Copy` bound here because `get_iterator` currently returns a copy. You could avoid the bound by making `get_iterator` return a `&T` instead.

As for `new`, you'll have to completely redesign it. If we keep it as is, the compiler gives error if we call it as `Holder::new` because `Holder` now has a type parameter, and the compiler cannot infer a type because `new` doesn't use any. To solve this, we can make `new` generic by using a trait to provide the constructor:

```
trait FactorCtor {
    fn new(factor: int) -> Self;
}
```

And then changing `new` to use that trait:

```
impl<T> Holder<T> where T: Iterator<int>+FactorCtor {
    pub fn new(factor : int) -> Holder<T> {
        Holder {
            x : FactorCtor::new(factor)
        }
    }
}
```

Because we have only one implementation of `FactorCtor` in this program, the compiler manages to infer `T` when calling `Holder::new`. If we add another implementation, e.g. `Adder`:

```
pub struct Adder {
    factor : int,
    current : int
}
impl FactorCtor for Adder {
    fn new(factor: int) -> Adder {
        Adder {
            factor: factor,
            current: 0
        }
    }
}
impl Iterator<int> for Adder {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<int> {
        if self.current > 10 {
            None
        }
        else {
            let current = self.current;
            self.current += 1;
            Some(current + self.factor)
        }
    }
}
```

Then we get a compiler error:

```
<anon>:72:9: 72:29 error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required
<anon>:72     let mut three_multiplier = Holder::new(3).get_iterator();
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

We can fix this by specifying `T` explicitly:

```
fn main() {
    let mut three_multiplier = Holder::<Multiplier>::new(3).get_iterator();
    for item in three_multiplier {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```